# Can I know names of all files I have shared with people on a network

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares, shared-folders

Is there any way I can know which all files I have shared with others (regardless of the different systems from which I shared the folders/files)?Because, few days back I had logged in to a different system and shared a folder to my friend from there, and now I am using a different system and my friend asked me for the path of that folder I shared with him(folder is in the other system). How do I get path of that file.

Comment: It is likely not shared anymore and needs to be shared again, assuming you mean a normal LAN network, not sharing over the internet (which is also a network)

Answer (score 1):

Run

> net share

Or go to Start, Control Panel, Administrative Tools, Computer Management.  Then, in the left frame, Computer Management (Local), System Tools, Shared Folders, Shares.

This doesn't show you the list of shared files; you cannot share files.  This shows the list of Shared Directories (not including files and subdirectories).  (The word "directory" is what some graphical programs call a "folder".)  To find what you actually asked for, which is the list of files, check out the contents with DIR or Windows Explorer.  e.g., once you know the name of the shared directory:

> dir /s \system\shared

If you are searching for a specific file, some operating systems (including Windows 7) will let you search for it like this:

> dir /s \system\shared*partial-name*